# Multiple swagger-ui html pages in a spring application

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am building an application where I would like to have two swagger urls:

http://localhost:8080/order-swagger.ui.html

http://localhost:8080/inventory-swagger.ui.html

I read many articles but did not find any solution.
What I found is that to define two docket beans but it does not effectively build two html pages. It creates 2 items in the upper right corner dropdown.

Much appreciated if you could provide how to do it.

Comment: I quite don't understand the requirement of  yours. But you can simply use the swagger for all your apis using the single url. like: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

Answer (score 7):

Along with the two `Docket` beans, you could add a couple of URL redirection rules to route `/order-swagger.ui.html` and `/inventory-swagger.ui.html` to `/swagger-ui.html` with the correct group selected. I defined a `WebMvcConfigurer` bean to do the redirection and then I got the two separate URLs, `http://localhost:8080/order-swagger.ui.html` and `http://localhost:8080/inventory-swagger.ui.html` available showing the API definitions of `/order` and `/inventory` endpoints respectively. Bean definitions below:

```java
    @Bean
    public Docket orderDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("order")
                .select().paths(path -> path.endsWith("/order"))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket inventoryDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("inventory")
                .select().paths(path -> path.endsWith("/inventory"))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
              registry.addRedirectViewController("order-swagger.ui.html", "/swagger-ui.html?urls.primaryName=order");
              registry.addRedirectViewController("inventory-swagger.ui.html", "/swagger-ui.html?urls.primaryName=inventory");
            }
        };
    }
```